# Create a binary adjacency matrix from a vector of indices

Tags: r, matrix, adjacency-matrix

Suppose I have a vector that looks like this:

```
x <- sample(5, 500, replace = TRUE)
```

so that each element corresponds to some index from 1 through 5.

What's an efficient way to create a binary adjacency matrix from this vector? To elaborate, the matrix `A` should be such that `A[i,j] = 1` if `x[i] = x[j]` and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In one line, you could do

```
outer(x, x, function(x, y) as.integer(x==y))
```

which returns

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    1     0
 [3,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    1     0
 [4,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    1     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    1     0
 [7,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [9,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    1     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
```

or, in two lines

```
myMat <- outer(x, x, "==")
myMat[] <- as.integer(myMat)
```

Check that they're the same.

```
identical(myMat, outer(x, x, function(x, y) as.integer(x==y)))
[1] TRUE
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- sample(5, 10, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Maybe also `sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) sapply(seq_along(x), function(j) as.integer(x[i] == x[j])))`